# split bigquery dataframe into chunks using dask

Tags: python, numpy, google-bigquery, dask, dask-distributed

I searched and tested different ways to find if I can be able to split bigquery dataframe into chunks of 75 rows, but couldn't find a way to do so. here is the senario:

I got a very large bigquery dataframe (millions of rows) using python and gcp SDK:

```
    from google.cloud import bigquery

    def returnBQResult(sqlQuery):
       bqClient = bigquery.Client()
       query_job = bqClient.query(sqlQuery)
       return query_job.to_dataframe()
```

I am looking for something similar to below numpy code but using dask and doing it parallel:

```
       dfBQResults=returnBQResult(sql)
       result=numpy.array_split(dfBQResults,75)
```